# Crash and data gone on audit backlog limit

Tags: centos

I am seeing crash and entering grub rescue mode on hard reboot after a few messages of "audit: backlog limit exceeded" on console.

Suddenly, the above messages are seen on conosle and at this point, no commands are executable saying "/bin/ls not found", etc. On reboot, it enters grub rescue mode. On seeing the file systems, none of the partitions have the boot files, requiring reinstallation. I have seen this repeatedly.

OS Version is CentOS 7.6.1810

Could anyone please help in throwing some light on this and suggest a solution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you saying that 1/ it crashes and doesn't work 2/ you reinstall and it's working again 3/ crashes again ... ? I'd suspect hardware, but it would be strange if you can reinstall without issue if there's failing hardware. Is reinstalling meaning from scractch with an iso image?

Comment: Yes, reinstallation is from scratch.  Reinstallation goes through and again gets into the same issue in a short while.